# How to split a bullet to many bullets after shooting

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

im a programming beginner and i have do to for a game we are coding a shotgun shot but have a problem and dont know how to do it

i want to add a bullet in the game that when you shoot it, it spits itself into a few and small bullets in small different directions, so basically a shotgun shot.

i already have a normal bullet with his position,vector and velocity , and you can shoot it already. but my problem is or the thing i dont understand is how i can split that one bullet after i shoot it in many bullets and how every of it gets it own position and moving vector

```
Bullet class{

Vector2 moveVector;
float speed =15; 

public void setMoveVector(float x, float y) {

        moveVector = new Vector2(x,y);}

// in that area here its for the bullet how it moving/acting including if the path is free or blocked by walls or something
if(map.pathFree(getX(), getY(), getX()+ moveVector.x * speed, getY() + moveVector.y * speed, this)) {
            setPosition(getX() + moveVector.x * speed, getY() + moveVector.y * speed);

    //somewhere here sould come the code splitting the bullet

//removing the bullet after a distance
            DistanceIndex += speed;
            if(DistanceIndex >= 1000) {
                remove();
            }
        }


        else
            HitWall();

        if(outsideMap()) this.remove();
    }
....        
    }
```

```
Obj Class 

//class/object/gamefigure using/creating the bullet

.....


public void shootingMethod(){

......


double direction_x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation));
double direction_y = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation));

Bullet bullet = new Bullet();

....

bullet.setMoveVector((float)direction_x, (float)directoin_y); 

}
```

[Picture of my problem i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuyH9.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To help you it's always usefull if you add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code to the question so everyone can see what you already have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a bunch of smaller bullets start off at the same position and travel in slightly different directions. You could rotate the velocity vectors slightly for each bullet to achieve this. If they aren't already, you can make the bullets sensors so overlapping is not a problem